# DataTable dt = ds.tables["put"]; why 'dt' is null?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

```
string sel = "select * from PUTIN";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["put"];
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
```

This is the code. When I run the line `DataRow row = dt.NewRow();`
 I get an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I find `dt` is null, why and how to slove it?

Comment: well, you just created an empty dataset, how do you expect it to contain the "put"-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataSet` is empty currently. You need to use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) here to fill your `DataSet`. Like this:

```
string sel = "select * from PUTIN";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sel,connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"put");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["put"];
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
```